# sql server query to group records

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

i would like to select from the following table:

PostTable

```
feed     dateinserted        count
  box1       2011-05-28 11:00    1000
  box2 
  box3
  box4 
  box5
  box6
```

the total number of records for the previous day where the feed is, 1, 3 and 5 i.e.
the feeds I need to retrieve totals for will just be selected based on what I need for instance it could be box4 and box 5...not specifically odd and even...I hope this makes it more clearer..

what I have for all records:

```
select sum(count) as [total] from PostTable where Cast(dateinserted as DATE) = 
 CAST(getdate()-1 as DATE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT feed, SUM(count) AS total FROM PostTable
WHERE Cast(dateinserted as DATE) = CAST(getdate()-1 as DATE) AND feed IN ('box1', 'box3', 'box4')
GROUP BY feed
```

Comment: what if I wanted the combined total for box1,box4,box3

Comment: SELECT SUM(count) AS total FROM PostTable
WHERE Cast(dateinserted as DATE) = CAST(getdate()-1 as DATE) AND feed IN ('box1', 'box3', 'box4')

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(count) AS Total FROM PostTable WHERE CONVERT(date, dateinserted, 101)=CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 101) AND feed % 2=1
```

After your edit the query would look something like this:

```
;with temp as(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY feed) AS RowNum, * from PostTable)
SELECT SUM(count) AS Total FROM temp WHERE CONVERT(date, dateinserted, 101)=CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 101) AND RowNum % 2=1
```

Please note the semicolon in the begining of WITH statement. it is necessary for the query to run successfully.

Comment: feed numbers are just sample data

Comment: @vbNewb: that's a MOD being performed on the last WHERE clause. This would get you odd-numbered feeds.

Comment: from your question i figured you'd want to see just odd numbers... if you wanna see even numbers of feed, replace it with feed % 2 = 0

Comment: no the actual feeds are listed as strings for example ...feeds.cnn.com...i cannot list the actual feeds

Comment: then your question is not asked correctly. If feeds are strings, how would you determine which one of them is 1, 3 and 5? One way you could do it, if you don't care about their order, just get the ROW_NUMBER() based on their alphabetical sort order and determine odd rows from it. Ex.: WHERE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FeedName) % 2 = 1

Answer (score 0):

**This may be help full to you for random odd number**

**id阿略
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9**

```
declare @input varchar(10)
set @input = 1
while @input < = 9
begin
select id from emp where id = @input
set @input = @input + 2
end
```